# Maven - "Package from transitive module dependency referenced, declare a direct dependency to fix."

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I never worked with Maven before, but after having a lot of problems with mockito dependencies in my Netbeans module, I decided to create a new one using Maven and move everything to this new project. After some time doing so, I managed to get the module running just ok.

The problem is that when I use some functionalities that require the Netbeans API I get an exception.

My guess is that the problem is in the dependencies declared in `pom.xml`. In some of the imports that I use in my application, I get the following message:

> Package from transitive module dependency referenced, declare a
>   direct dependency to fix.

When I clean and build or run `mvn clean install` in the root directory I get this error:

> Project uses classes from transitive module
>   org.netbeans.api:org-netbeans-modules-projectapi:jar:RELEASE73 which
>   will not be accessible at runtime.
>       To fix the problem, add this module as direct dependency. For OSGi bundles that are supposed to be wrapped in NetBeans modules, use the
>   useOSGiDependencies=false parameter

In the `org.codehaus.mojo` plugin declaration (which was the only one that had the `useOSGiDependencies` tag) I tried to change `useOSGiDependencies=true` to `useOSGiDependencies=false` but that didn't work. I also tried to change `RELEASE73` to `RELEASE82`, since I am using Netbeans 8.2 but that didn't work as well. I also tried a bunch of other possible solutions that I found on google, but none seemed to work for me.

These are the Netbeans api dependencies that  I have in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-project-libraries</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE73</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-api-annotations-common</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE82</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-util</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE82</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-awt</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE82</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-core</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE73</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

I looked everywhere but couldn't find a straightforward answer on how to declare a direct dependency.

Can anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After digging a bit more, I found that I had to add all the dependencies manually. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24991589/2699664) helped me a lot.

I just lack experience with maven. Basically I googled *org-netbeans-modules-projectapi:jar:RELEASE73 maven* entered the first link and added the needed dependency to my project.